# System.UnauthorisedAccessException during WebClient request C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Currently using the following code to attempt to download PDF files from webpages and store them in a folder selected by the user. Every time it runs I get a message telling me Access to a path is denied.

Error message:

> ```
>   [0] "Link was not downloaded due to: System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path ***** is denied.\r\n   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)\r\n   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)\r\n   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)\r\n   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)\r\n   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)\r\n   at TextFileToDownloadedPDF.Form1.DownloadPDF() in *****\\Form1.cs:line 103 link address: *address to download pdf, removed for security reasons* object {string}
> ```

Code:

```
string source = client.DownloadString(htmlLink);
string title = Regex.Match(source, @"\<title\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</title\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["Title"].Value;

client.DownloadFile(htmlLink, destinationDirectory + title);
```

Tried looking all over the forums but no solutions seem to work. I'd like to know what is going wrong not just a solution if possible as I am trying to learn to code, I'm no pro.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you need to be authenticated before downloading the PDF

Comment: What is the value of 'destinationDirectory + title'?

Comment: The value would be something like C:\...Desktop\TestFolder\BlahBlah.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Right click on that folder, goto permissions and add the "Network Service" user - Right click on that folder, goto permissions and add the "Everyone" user

Comment: How can I get this to work if I send this to a client? As Im not sure they will be able to add that permission to the folder.

Comment: Permission to the folder required  where actual files is, must be on file server.

Comment: I fixed it without adding the network service user but I'm not entirely sure what I did to fix it... Think I changed the directory things were located into somewhere else and viola!